# Is there a way to call the destructor of a replaced element when using std::replace?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of objects where I want to replace one element by another.
Using std::replace seemed appropriate, so I gave it a try.

I was concerned about the whereabouts of the replaced element though, so I did some tests :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class A {
    public:
    A(const int ii) : i(ii) { std::cout << "Constructor " << i << std::endl;}
    ~A(){std::cout << "Destructor " << i << std::endl;}

    auto operator ==(const A& a){ return i == a.i;}
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.reserve(4);
    v.emplace_back(10);
    v.emplace_back(20);
    v.emplace_back(40);
    v.emplace_back(30);
    for(const auto& elt : v){
        std::cout << elt.i << ' ';
    }
     std::cout << std::endl;

    std::replace(v.begin(), v.end(), v[2], A(25));
    for(const auto& elt : v){
        std::cout << elt.i << ' ';
    }
     std::cout << "End of program" << std::endl;
}
```

Third element of the vector is replaced, but as you can see the replaced object destructor isn't called :

```
Constructor 10
Constructor 20
Constructor 40
Constructor 30
10 20 40 30 
Constructor 25
Destructor 25
10 20 25 30 End of program
Destructor 10
Destructor 20
Destructor 25
Destructor 30
```

As the behaviour is the same on every compiler, I suppose it's intended, but is there a way to have the destructor called in that case ?

Testing example :
https://godbolt.org/z/YTaKcrTEn

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) on `std::replace`:

> Because the algorithm takes `old_value` and `new_value` by reference, it
> can have unexpected behavior if either is a reference to an element of
> the range `[first, last)`.

Therefore, this is wrong:

```
std::replace(v.begin(), v.end(), v[2], A(25));
```

Indeed, we can't choose `old_value` to be a reference to `v[2]` as done here. Consider instead:

```
A to_replace{v[2]};  // copy
std::replace(v.begin(), v.end(), to_replace, A(25));
```

You can also force the copy without using an additional variable (as Staz suggests):

```
std::replace(v.begin(), v.end(), A{v[2]}, A(25));
```

Comment: There's a difference between undefined and unexpected behavior. I don't see any reason why it would be UB. Also an additional variable isn't required, `std::replace(v.begin(), v.end(), A{V[2]}, A(25));` should be okay.

Comment: @Staz Indeed, I edited a few seconds ago to correct that. :)

Comment: Thanks both for the detailed explanation, that make sense ... and it works nicely !

Answer (score 0):

No. `replace` uses assignment, and assignment requires a *live* object.

If your type has a meaningful destructor (ie: rule of 5), and your type is assignable, then assignment ought to be effectively equivalent to calling the destructor and then doing placement-`new` on the object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is spot on. I chose the other one nevertheless as it included fixed examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misunderstanding of what a destructor does.

The destructor takes an object, and turns it into "not an object" (just raw memory).  That is the opposite of a constructor, which takes raw memory and turns it into an object.

In your code, you assign a new value to an object (via `std::replace`). That does not create new objects, nor does it destroy any objects - so there are no constructor or destructor calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I must say that it had me scratching my head for a while ... but @chi 's answer pointed the problem in the code I posted, and I finally understood your point.